# How can I change SVG fill color inside an object without putting any css code inside the svg file

Tags: css, svg, hover

How can I change the SVG fill color on hover inside an object tag without putting any CSS code inside the svg file? Here's my code:

```
<div class="icon-holder">
    <object data="http://useaible.com/wp-content/themes/storefront/assets/images/icons/bulb-round.svg"></object>
</div>
```

I know that CSS won't work if it's not inside the SVG-file. Is there another way on implementing a hover effect without using inline SVG nor using CSS inside the SVG-file?

Comment: Is your html file on the same domain as the SVG file?

Comment: Nope. I separated my svg file on another folder. I don't want to use inline svg because it would fill up a lot of space on my html file.

Comment: If it's not the same domain then there may be nothing you can do. Your comment sound like you didn't understand the question though.

Answer (score -2):

You can use SVG sprites. Define your svg after your `body` like that :

```
<svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icon-facebook" viewBox="0 0 16 32">
    <title>facebook</title>
    <path class="path1" d="M4.973 30.593v-13.872h-4.973v-4.984h4.974v-4.433c0-4.595 2.775-7.303 6.874-7.303 1.964 0 3.66 0.211 4.152 0.276v5.053l-3.393-0.001c-2.229 0-2.646 1.106-2.646 2.66v3.749h5.711l-0.807 4.984h-4.904v13.872h-4.988z"></path>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

and call it in your code :

```
<svg class="icon-facebook"><use xlink:href="#icon-facebook"></use></svg>
```

That way you can aply CSS on it.